# Watermelon - picking and managing them during heat

Tags: food-preservation, heat, watermelon

There are a lot of posts and videos on the internet about picking up the correct watermelon. Sure. I get that. My question varies a little different.

I currently live in the UAE and climates here reach around 49c and more. So despite the fact that we pick watermelon we want to know the best way to preserve it. Supermarkets here and the farmers market leave them out.

I take them home and immediately put in the fridge. About a day later I take the melon, cut it up and will leave half in the fridge and other half chopped in a bowl and also can leave that in the fridge and we will consume it with meals taking it in and out over the next few days. Few problems:

- The watermelon gets very watery - dark red blotches so it becomes overripe
- The sweetness goes quickly

How can we keep it sweet and keep it maintained - what are some tips you guys use for family and preserving it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be different varieties of watermelon that behave differently, so I can't guarantee that this will work for you.

The way I've always done it is to only cut up what I'm going to eat.

We cut across the watermelon in the shorter direction, starting at one end, producing circles about 1-1.5 inch (2-3 cm) thick.

Here's an image of what removing the first slice looks like:

[image: End slice cutting off]

You can cut these circles into wedges or remove the rind and cut into pieces.

[image: wedges of Watermelon]

This leaves the remainder of the watermelon intact with only a single side open to the air, and that end is covered in plastic wrap (cling film) and stored in the refrigerator.

[image: Half watermelon with plastic wrap]